# Как с помощью fancybox показывать и текст и картинку

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, fancybox, lightbox

Добрый день друзья, для lightbox использую плагин fancybox, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно одновременно показывать и текст и кратнику внутри lighbox.

$parent_id = 5;

$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
  'child_of' => $parent_id,
  'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ){
  foreach( $sub_cats as $cat ){
    echo ''. $cat->name .'

';

```
# получаем записи из рубрики
$myposts = get_posts( array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'category'    => $cat->cat_ID,
  'orderby'     => 'post_date',
  'order'       => 'DESC',
) );
`введите сюда код`# выводим записи
global $post;
foreach($myposts as $post){
  setup_postdata($post);
  echo '<div class="single_product">
  <a class="outer" href="'. get_field("image_link").'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail() . '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>
  <div class="inner_block">'.get_field("image_link").'<h6></h6></div>
  </a> 

  </div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем глобальную переменную пост
```

}
}

html выглядить вот так:

```
<div class="single_product">
      <a class="outer" href="prod3.jpg">
      <img width="232" height="327" src="prod3.jpg"  alt="prod3">
      <p>Фарш говяжий</p>
      </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: какой текст?  - название картинки или что то большое?

Comment: и код который вы показали как то связанно с lightbox ?

Comment: что то больше! Этот код я использую для вывода рубрик в wordpress, мне нужно чтобы при клике на картинку появлялась большая картника с некоторым описанем(5 - 8 параграфов)

Answer (score 1):

Вот посмотрите пример, думаю вам поможет

```js
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow : function() {
        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');
        
        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
        
        this.title = alt;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>


<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="First picture"/></a>

<a rel="gallery" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="Second picture"/></a>
```

Comment: Мне нужно не просто текст вывести, а html с такого вида как <div> <h1></h1> <p> </p> </div> и т.д